# jQuery: Move element position

Tags: javascript, jquery

In each div, there are two buttons: higher and lower. When 'higher' is clicked, if this div is not at the top position, then it is moved higher than original. When 'lower' is clicked, then the element will be moved lower than original.

The question is: How to the elements can be moved up and down of with respect to another element?

```
<div>
    <div id="a1">a1<input name='higher' type='button' value='higher'/><input name='lower' type='button' value='lower'/></div>
    <div id="a2">a2<input name='higher' type='button' value='higher'/><input name='lower' type='button' value='lower'/></div>
    <div id="a3">a3<input name='higher' type='button' value='higher'/><input name='lower' type='button' value='lower'/></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try something like this: http://www.jsfiddle.net/yijiang/hwPPP/

With `insertAfter` and `insertBefore` we can move the parent of the buttons up and down.

```
$('#list').delegate('input[type="button"]', 'click', function() {
    var parent = $(this).parent();

    if(this.value === 'higher'){
        parent.insertBefore(parent.prev());
    } else {
        parent.insertAfter(parent.next());
    }

    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should look into something like JqueryUI Sortable:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/

Otherwise you could use next()/previous() and insertBefore()/insertAfter() jquery functions together:

```
$("#a1").insertAfter($('#a1').next());
```

Comment: althrough this achieve my request, but i need add a plugin in my project,i still want to find some manual way to achieve this

Comment: it was just an example on how you can use the functions...The answer above is a nice answer to your request